# Large file size with forms?

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

I'm using codeigniter, but what I've done is made a small upload form. When I try to upload a 49kb file it works, when I try to upload a 14mb file, not only does it not work, but it seems to be refusing to see it as a post. `$this->input->post()` is returning false. That is before all the CI code that checks upload size etc. So I don't understand what can be keeping the file from being uploaded all the way.

Comment: the php.ini directives, there's a limit in file uploads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has file size restrictions, default usually at 10MB. If you have access to php.ini, edit `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`.

You can typically also accomplish this by adding the following to your .htaccess file, if you're on Apache:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
php_value post_max_size 100M
```

Other flags that might affect your success are `max_execution_time`, `max_input_time` and `memory_limit`.